# Minimum and recommended requirement for Tomcat 7 or Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, memory, processor

What is the minimum and recommended requirements for tomcat 6 or Tomcat 7. Please provide memory requirement, Disk Space Requirement and Processor requirement ?

Comment: Might be nice to accept this answer: score of 15 nearly 3 years later. :p

Comment: Nearly 3 years later ad he still didn't accept it.

Answer (score 36):

Tomcat 6/7 itself can run in about 12MiB of heap. Tomcat 7.0.35 takes up exactly 13412390 bytes on your disk with no applications installed and no log files. If you don't install any web applications or write any log files, Tomcat requires 13MiB of disk space. Processor requirements are all dependent upon the JVM. I suspect that a JVM requires a 32-bit processor with at least one core.

So, basically anything that you can successfully boot that was manufactured in the last 20 years should be able to run Tomcat 6 or 7.

Recommended system configuration: most cores, most memory, and most disk space you can afford.

Obviously, nobody can give you any good advice without any input. I've seen web applications that run extremely well under expected load on a single core with 512MiB of memory installed and minimal disk usage. On the other hand, I've seen multi-core machines with 32GiB of memory fall-over because of improper configuration, badly-written software and inadequate capacity-planning.

**EDIT 2016-07-13**

For Tomcat 8 running on Oracle Java 8, a Tomcat server running only a trivial web applications starts up inside of ~24MiB. Tomcat 8 is required to process a lot more things on startup and when deploying a web application, so additional heap is necessary. It may be possible to pare this down, but I just took an existing Tomcat instance I had and started it with no web applications deployed (except a trivial one to report memory usage) to see what it looked like.

Answer (score 13):

Since it is most probably that you are going to run Java EE application on your Tomcat I would refer you to Java EE 7 SDK System Reuirements:

[Java EE 7 SDK System Requirements](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/javaee7sdk-readme-1957703.html#System_Requirements)

> The minimum and recommended memory and disk space requirements are as follows:
>
> - Minimum memory: 1 GB
> - Recommended memory: 2 GB for Windows platforms, 1 GB for non-Windows platforms
> - Minimum disk space: 250 MB
> - Recommended disk space: 500 MB

Nevertheless I totally agree with **Christopher Schultz** that final requirements should be based on non-functional requirements for your application and, of course, JVM should be configured properly.

Comment: FWIW, if you are going to run Java EE applications, you should probably be using [Apache TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)

Comment: Just to clarify, Java EE (Enterprise Edition) is ***not* required** to run Servlet-based web apps in Tomcat. I've run many Tomcat servers on Mac OS X and Windows on top of plain old Java SE (Standard Edition). If you need a few of the EE technologies, first check if you can install specific supporting jar files rather that moving to EE.

Answer (score 5):

If we take a look at service.bat file shipped in Tomcat 7/8 there are default memory options set JvmMs (Initial memory pool size) to 128 MB and JvmMx (Maximum memory pool size) to 256 MB. So it looks like Tomcat developers have determined that a "thin" version of Tomcat running as Windows Service requires just 128...256 MB of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

This fully depends on the application being deployed and load this application will have.

I would almost categorise this as a "trick" question from organisations such as vendors or system integrators when doing infrastructure planning as part of activities such as RFP submission.